# Seeking Information regarding EDI

Tags: biztalk

I'm not sure if this is a correct place, but I can't think of another to ask this.
I've been looking for about 2 weeks to figure out where I can find information about EDI software and infrastructure. I'm building a SAAS solution which will incorporate EDI, problem is I only have knowledge of EDI from a operational standpoint, I.E. using it. I tried google, and a few other sources, but most talk about translating EDI, not actual transmission between partners or other intricacies. Apparently it's a very protected industry :)
I was hoping someone can recommend me to a place that has this information.
Why am I looking to build an EDI server instead of using a VAN, in the industry I am in, most VANs are operated by competitors, so business wise it may not be a good idea to use them :)
I have access to BizTalk server also, not sure if that's of any use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an outside [Electronic Data Interchange (EDI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) solution, especially  if you're not aware of the nuances of the process: Configuring new trading partners, X12 formats, maintaining uptime, notification of failures, error handling, etc. They are also better at this than you, so the process should be streamlined.

I've worked with third-party [EDI VANs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_network) for my customers for this reason. The customers aren't well-equipped to do it on their own. And yes, you can find VANs who are not competitors to you... [An example](http://www.swc.com/solutions/edi-dx).

Comment: Zephyr, from SWC, is a great solution. Of course, full disclosure: I work at SWC :)

Comment: @rex Yep... and you guys handle most of my client EDI needs.